# Show List of Terms (not posts) that have been Recently Updated?

Tags: terms, updates

Is it possible to prepare a list of terms that have been recently updated?

For example: I have custom fields attached to my terms and I would like to show a list of terms that have been updated say in last 24hrs.

Note: I do not want a list of terms in which post inside have been updated, simple a list of terms which have been recently edited and updated.

Comment: Looking at a normal WordPress Database, it doesn't look like WP keeps track of when Terms were last edited or updated like it does Posts. You would probably have to create your own options or even a separate database table and store these yourself.

Comment: Howdy, Thanks for your input. That is kinda what I had figured.